# 'Unlimited' free trial of Windows Server 2008 by deleting and reinstalling VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, virtualbox, licensing

I am using Virtual Machine software (VirtualBox) to learn Windows Server 2008 R2 Network Infrastructure (70-642).  Trouble is - I'm learning at an extremely slow pace and so the trial periods of my virtual machines are close to running out.

If I delete the VMs then install WS2008R2 from scratch on new VMs is that violating the acceptable use policy of Microsoft?

I am aware that I can extend the trial, but it seems I can only do that by 10 days at a time.   Also I think having to re-install from scratch is a good way to reinforce the knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: In the US (I explicitly disclaim any knowledge of licensing otherwise): After the 180 day trial, exclusive of extensions or "valid licensing", you have no right to use the software (there's no limitations on that... (*thou shall not*). "The Software" in this case applies to the installation of Windows on your computer. It also  applies to the source media you used to create that installation. You may obtain new source media to create a new installation and may enter into a new 180 trial license however. [Restrictions on use and such apply](http://tinyurl.com/cdyrvst).

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your question directly but I would suggest purchasing a TechNet subscription so as not to have to worry about those issues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh442910

Answer (score 1):

`slmgr /rearm` will give you an additional 30 day window. You can rearm up to three times. This will give you an additional 3 months of trial time without having to reinstall.

Also, make sure you know your DNS for 70-642 ;)

As to the actual legality if it - we're sysadmins, not lawyers. We generally refrain from answering these kinds of questions here.